# Visual Studio 2017: C1083: Cannot open source file. Absolute path mangled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, googletest, visual-studio-project

I am attempting to uplift a project from VS2010 to VS2017. I have done several others without any (unexpected) issues. I am now attempting to do the same with a Google Test project, however when I attempt to build the project I get:

```
1><source>.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '<source>.cpp': No such file or directory
```

This happens for all of the source code in this project.

I have attempted to clean, rebuild, delete and re-add the project to the solution but to no avail. The only indication I have that something is wrong is that the file properties indicate incorrect 'Full Path' fields:

```
...\hared.gtest\<ource>.cpp
```

The full path for this file should be:

```
...\shared.gtest\<source>.cpp
```

So the first letter is missing from both the project directory and the source file in the 'Full Path' field.

I have no idea what might be at issue here so any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Any news on this? Got the same problem when copying a project to a different location.